# Use an AppReceiptId to verify a user's identity in a Windows Store App?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to be able to use the AppReceiptId from the result of CurrentApp.GetAppReceiptAsync() and tie it to a username in my backend service, to verify that the user has actually purchased the app.

I know I'm supposed to use CurrentAppSimulator in place of CurrentApp, but CurrentAppSimulator.GetAppReceiptAsync() always returns a different, random value for AppReceiptId. This makes it difficult to test with my service.

Is there a way to make it always return the same value, other than just using a hardcoded one? I'm worried that when I replace CurrentAppSimulator with CurrentApp and submit it to the store, it won't behave the way I expect it to. In the real world, the AppReceiptId won't ever change, right?

The Code I use to get AppReceiptId:

```
var receiptString = await CurrentAppSimulator.GetAppReceiptAsync();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(receiptString);

var ReceiptNode = (from s in doc.ChildNodes 
                   where s.NodeName == "Receipt"
                   select s).Single();

var AppReceiptNode = (from s in ReceiptNode.ChildNodes
                      where s.NodeName == "AppReceipt"
                      select s).Single();

var idNode = (from s in AppReceiptNode.Attributes
              where s.NodeName == "Id"
              select s).Single();

string id = idNode.NodeValue.ToString();
```

id will always be some random Guid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CurrentApp.GetAppReceiptAsync().Id** is a unique ID for the actual *purchase*. Although it does technically represent a unique purchase made by a single Windows ID, it doesn't represent the user themselves and I don't think there's any guarantee on the durability of that ID.

Would you be better suited using the Windows Live SDK to track the actual user identity across devices?

At any rate, to answer your original question, no I don't believe there's any way to make it return the same ID all the time. The only logical place for that functionality would be in the **WindowsStoreProxy.xml** file, and I don't see anything in the schema that would allow you to specify this information.